# For Article: How do you use fancy header/footer style for first page and start new header and footer sequence on the second page?

Tags: header-footer

I have come across posts on how to not use fancy header at all after first page, but I want to use fancy header style specific to the first page of the article and then the pages following will have its own sequential style. And I have yet to find the answer, or maybe I am just not wording the question correctly. And I am only a few weeks into learning Latex. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want the first page of the article to have a specific header/footer style and then change the style on the second page of the article for the remainder of the article. For example: On the first page, for the header, I want to have "journal name" centered; and then page number centered in the footer. Starting page 2 and for the rest of the article, headers on even pages "author name" right; page num. left; footer "journal name" right. Odd page numbers: "article title" left; page number right; footer "journal name" left.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) for this. I suggest defining each style separately - `firstpage` for the first page and `otherpages` for subsequent pages. Then use `otherpages` as the default page style and `firstpage` only for the first page via `\thispagestyle{firstpage}` after `\maketitle`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

% Declare the page style for the first page
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[C]{\journalname}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  %\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule (default)
}
% Declare the page style for other pages
\fancypagestyle{otherpages}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[ER]{\authorname}%
  \fancyhead[OL]{\articletitle}%
  \fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}%
  \fancyfoot[ER,OL]{\journalname}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  %\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule (default)
}

\newcommand{\articletitle}{Article title}
\newcommand{\journalname}{Journal name}
\newcommand{\authorname}{Author name}

\title{\articletitle}
\author{\authorname}

\pagestyle{otherpages}% Set default page stale

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firstpage}% CHange page style for THIS page only

\sloppy\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

I store the journal name, article title and author in separate variables, since they're used in multiple places (inside `\maketitle` and in the header/footer declarations).

Comment: Thank you for responding! I will try this out. I greatly appreciate it. :)

Comment: OK, one aspect I forgot to note. The title of the article on the preceding pages following the first page, needs to be a shortened or abbreviated form. Sorry for not mentioning that first.

Comment: And how do I reduce the spacing in between the lines of the journal title on the front page? Do I insert \vspace{} in between the lines?

Comment: @BrianJOrrPhD: I created a new command `\articleshorttitle` that has the abbreviated form in it. For adjusting the space: That forms part of `\@maketitle` and requires a patch (thanks to [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)). Here's the [full code](https://pastebin.com/raw/dFPzsQ2P).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I cannot get the spacing between the vertical lines in the title reduced. I will post the code so you can see.

Comment: Actually, it didn't work. I am not sure how to post code. I selected the code option and it was all jumbled.